Insert landscape A3 page in A4 document with KOMA and geometry but keep margins
I want to insert a A3 landscape page in a A4 document. But when I do so, it keeps changing the margins. I found this question, which helped me to correct them for the left and right margin, but somehow \areaset keeps ignoring my \textheight-option in \areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}. If I check the head and foot distances to the page edge, they are different than on the A4-pages. You can also see that before I change the pagestyle the \textheight is 674.33041pt, but after the \areaset-command it is 634.45541pt.
Unfortunately I didn't know about better before I set up the document, so I used the geometry package and a KOMA-script document together. Probably I wouldn't have that problem if I kept to just one of these two. But now the document has grown a lot, so I don't want to change anything about the original layout.
Here is a MWE. Since it produces three pages and you can just narrowly see the described problem, I didn't include a picture of it.
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt,twoside=false,headsepline=true,numbers=noenddot,areasetadvanced]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead*[]{}
\chead*[]{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ifoot*[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\section{section a}
some text

\showthe\textheight
\storeareas\normalpapersize
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}
\showthe\textheight

some more text
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait}
\normalpapersize

even more text
\end{document}

I realized that \areaset recalculates all the values to describe the page layout, so I tried to correct it by manually overwriting the lenghts for the header and foot by storing them before changing to A3 and restoring them afterwards like in the following MWE. This seems to work just fine for the header, but the foot is still offset (even more than before). It seems to me a little bit, that the new \textheight is just ignored.
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt,twoside=false,headsepline=true,numbers=noenddot,areasetadvanced]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=3cm,bottom=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead*[]{}
\chead*[]{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ifoot*[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\section{section a}
some text

\showthe\textheight
\storeareas\normalpapersize
\newlength{\oldtextheight}
\setlength{\oldtextheight}{\textheight}
\newlength{\oldfootskip}
\setlength{\oldfootskip}{\footskip}
\newlength{\oldtopmargin}
\setlength{\oldtopmargin}{\topmargin}
\newlength{\oldheadheight}
\setlength{\oldheadheight}{\headheight}
\newlength{\oldheadsep}
\setlength{\oldheadsep}{\headsep}
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr 2\textwidth+2\oddsidemargin+2in\relax}{\textheight}
\setlength{\textheight}{\oldtextheight}
\setlength{\topmargin}{\oldtopmargin}
\setlength{\headheight}{\oldheadheight}
\setlength{\headsep}{\oldheadsep}
\setlength{\footskip}{\oldfootskip}
\showthe\textheight

some more text
\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,paper=portrait}
\normalpapersize

even more text
\end{document}

After that I tried to recalculate \footskip to somewhat like \setlength{\footskip}{\dimexpr \oldfootskip+\oldtextheight-\textheight\relax}, but that still doesn't exactly match the layout like it was before the change to A3. Furthermore, if I change back to A4 and restore the old layout, the foot keeps like it was in the A3 layout. So I discarded changing the \footskip.
Probably I forgot to reset/overwrite some lengths, but I couldn't find a clear say in the KOMA-script documentation on which lenghts \areaset recalculates.
As stated in an answer to this question, I could generate a separate A3 file and include it. I really don't want to do that since I need all references and links to work in the A3 page.

I didn't until now, but to me it seems to be more or less like my first MWE? If I set up my document in the same way, the foot is still off.

okay, but when I comment \areaset and use \newgeometry{} it doesn't change the pagesize, even though I have \KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}

that was probably the information I was missing. Now it does the trick perfectly like I wanted it. Thanks a lot

that wasn't my question. I just stumbled over it, while I was looking for a solution.

IMHO the third example in esdd's answer is exactly what you are searching for. So I'm sure, that this is a duplicate.

I see your point, it does indeed solve my problem as well, but the margins are different to when I do it with \activateareas. Since this command isn't used in any of the answers, I think it makes it different.

esdd uses \KOMAoptions{DIV=last} instead of \activateareas. I've tested this and the result is the same as with the \activatereas in my first example. Because of the \newgeometry{margin=3cm} after the DIV=last the geometry settings overwrite the DIV=last. So if you have other margins, maybe you forgot to change the margin=2.5cm in that answer to your settings.

I am pretty sure, I modified everything right. But I got a warning about using DIV=last, so I maybe didn't check close enough if it matches my needs. If you say you got the same results, I agree that it is a duplicate.

The KOMA-Script author also explains, that \KOMAoptions{DIV=last} usually can be used instead of \activateareas when using \newgeometry to reactivate the margins: → https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_A3_landscape_to_A4/ or https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_A3_landscape_to_A4/

@Schweinebacke Know this. I've asked him to add an example like this to the user manual, but he decided to add it to the wiki.

IMHO, what you want is something like:
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt,twoside=false,headsepline=true,numbers=noenddot,usegeometry]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead*[]{}
\chead*[]{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ifoot*[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\section{section a}
some text

\showthe\textheight
\storeareas\normalpapersize

\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\activateareas% or any setting of DIV or BCOR, e.g. \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
\newgeometry{margin=3cm}
\showthe\textheight

some more text
\cleardoubleoddpage
\normalpapersize

even more text
\end{document}

or
\documentclass[paper=A4,12pt,twoside=false,headsepline=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead*[]{}
\chead*[]{}
\ohead{\headmark}
\automark[subsection]{section}
\ifoot*[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}

\section{section a}
some text

\showthe\textheight
\storeareas\normalpapersize

\cleardoubleoddpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{.5\paperwidth}
\activateareas
\showthe\textheight

some more text
\cleardoubleoddpage
\normalpapersize

even more text
\end{document}

The first examples uses typearea's option usegeometry and \newgeometry to change the page layout of the landscape page, the second does not need geometry (but also works with it). Both examples are adaptions of the \storeareas example in the KOMA-Script manuals. Similar examples can be found in the KOMA-Script Wiki in English and in German.

The second one was the solution I was looking for. Somehow I missed the \activateareas. Now it behaves exactly like I wanted it to.
